# how can I make this font size small smoothly without jumps?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm trying to reduce the size of the font gradually. But it looks like it shakes while turning small. How to make it look smooth?

```css
.name:hover {
  color: green;
  transition-property: font-size;
  transition-duration: 2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  font-size: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="name">Name</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `transform:scale` instead:

```css
.name {
    transition: transform 2s;
    transform-origin: left
}
.name:hover {
    color: green;
    transform: scale(0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="name">Name</div>
```